# How do I get total GPRS usage in KBs on a Windows Mobile Device?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, gprs

Anyone knows how to do this programmatically? I looked at the registry keys but I couldn't find anything. I don't know maybe I missed it. 
Under the registry key HKLM/Software/Microsoft/shell/cumulativecalltimers/line_0/ there are the values "OutgoingDataPhoneLifeTime" and "OutgoingDataPhoneLifeTimeNumCalls"; but these don't seem to be what I am looking for. They give a value in terms of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFAIK Windows Mobile does not tack this information.  You will have to do it yourself if you really want it.

I've not done exactly what you want but I know there are only 2 places you could track GPRS information.  You either have to use [TAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918634.aspx) (which I'm not sure that you could track GPRS information with) or you need to drop down and use the [RIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920475.aspx) API layer (which is what I beleave the TAPI layer uses).